# Posting XML in dotnet 6 web wpi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters(); //I added xml

 public class WeatherForecast
    {
        
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

       
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
        
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class WeatherForecastList //Class I want to post in xml
    {
       
        public List<WeatherForecast> Forecasts { get; set; }
    }

        [HttpPost] //Experimental method
        public ActionResult<WeatherForecastList> GetWeather([FromBodyAttribute] 
              WeatherForecastList WeatherForecast)
        {
            return Ok(WeatherForecast);
        }

<WeatherForecastList>
   <Forecasts>
      <WeatherForecast>
      .
      .
      </WeatherForecast>
   </Forecasts
</WeatherForecastList>
```

I am currently experimenting with making posts using XML instead of JSON in dotnet 6. I can get it to work if I just post a simple object. I would like to understand how to post more complex types with nesting and lists of other types. The goal is to get the xml and then return it. Id like the structure of the xml to look something like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add xml formatters in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

and add `Produces` attribute to your controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Update**

You should add `Content-Type: application/xml` in headers, or if you are calling it from swagger just change request body type here:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. My question is not outputting xml, but getting it parse it from the body of a post. Im having a hard time parsing into an object that has a list of other objects. See the xml I included

Comment: @RomanOwensby I am sorry for unclear answer, for posting xml you need to add header in your request Content-Type: application/xml and your api could parse xml requests